# Stored procedure to find the number of records from input table name

Tags: procedure

In a stored procedure, I pass a table name as the input variable.  I want to return the number of rows of this table with that stored procedure.

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
clear screen; 
set serveroutput on; 
declare  tbl_nm varchar2(50); 
create or replace procedure table_cnt(table_name in varchar2(50), cnt out integer) as 
begin 
tbl_nm:=table_name; 
select count(*) into cnt from tbl_nm; 
end;
```

working in oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function from AskTOM, you can refer to it

```
create or replace 
function get_rows( p_tname in varchar2 ) return number 
as 
l_columnValue number default NULL; 
begin 
execute immediate 
'select count(*) 
from ' || p_tname INTO l_columnValue; 

return l_columnValue; 
end; 
/ 

select user, table_name, 
get_rows( user||'.'||table_name) cnt 
from user_tables 
/
```